Repeat the same header in all pages of RTF report
Actually i want the first section in this page highlighted in yellow on this page to be repeated as a header across all  pages, corresponding to the number of products the client possesses. This section contains client information along with a summary of its product. Conversely, the sections highlighted in black represent each individual product mentionned in the summary, each to be displayed on its respective page. Thank you.
I want to repeat same header in all pages by the number of product that the client has.

What have you tried so far? Can you provide some examples you seem to reference?
